# HTMLAgilityPack get class innerText

Tags: c#, class, http, html-agility-pack, innertext

I am trying to get the `innerText` of a class.
This is my code:

```
using (HttpClient clientduplicate = new HttpClient())
{
    clientduplicate.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident / 6.0)");

    using (HttpResponseMessage responseduplicate = await clientduplicate.GetAsync(@"https://www.investing.com/news/stock-market-news/warren-buffett:-i-bought-$12-billion-of-stock-after-trump-won-456954")
    using (HttpContent contentduplicate = responseduplicate.Content)
    {
        try
        {
            string resultduplicate = await contentduplicate.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var websiteduplicate = new HtmlDocument();
            websiteduplicate.LoadHtml(resultduplicate);

            var titlesduplicate = websiteduplicate.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "arial_14 clear WYSIWYG newsPage");
            var match = Regex.Match(titlesduplicate.InnerText, @"(.*?)<!--", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value;

            Debug.WriteLine(match.TrimStart());
        }
        catch(Exception ex1)
        {
            var dialog2 = new MessageDialog(ex1.Message);
            await dialog2.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that this will also return me the text on the picture. I can find a workaround but I was wondering if there is an other approach on this.
Something simpler/faster.

Plus when I use this on other articles/URLs there are other minor bugs.

Comment: You can cleanup your node with an xpath query like this `titlesduplicate.SelectNodes("./img")?.ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());` And for selecting titlesduplicate, use `var titlesduplicate = websiteduplicate.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'newsPage')]");`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the bugs are?

Comment: @GantTheWanderer alphabetic encodings, letters changed to html. Minor things.

Comment: I would take Hung Cao's answer, remove the offensive material.  Otherwise you need to be a lot more accurate with your selector.  What information are you trying to gather and what are you going to do with it?

Comment: @GantTheWanderer can you describe other minor bugs? Maybe I can help

Comment: @GantTheWanderer a bug I can seem to work out is that it doesn't get newlines. All text comes in one line. Any idea on this? It is not a big problem because I will display that on a textblock which will fix it, just wondering

Comment: If I were a web server I would not  be sending out new line characters because they are not necessary in HTML and many other kinds of markup.  Newlines make it easy for humans to read, but its just wasted space for a computer to parse through, extra data to needlessly transmit through the pipes.

Comment: Well said. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to remove the carousel div before getting innerText:
`doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Id.Equals("imgCarousel"))?.Remove();`

Comment: This will throw `System.NullReferenceException` if `imgCarousel` doesn't exist. I fixed it but edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I see. I added `?` to check for null reference. I hope you know this c# 6 syntax

Comment: A bug I can seem to work out is that it doesn't get newlines. All text comes in one line. Any idea on this? I am adding this here in case you want to help with those small debugs

Comment: Can you describe more? Btw, is there any reason you had to use regex? IMO, we shouldn't use regex for parsing html.

Comment: The reason I use regex is because I don't want all part of the `innerText`.

Comment: Which part you don't want?